# Timeout issues with Nodejs MySQL Connection

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I am getting a timeout error while trying to connect to my SQL server using node.js mysql package.

Node Version v20.8.0

Code:

```
// MySQL Internal connection configuration
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: '192.168.8.173',
    user: '[username]',
    password: '[password]',
    database: 'cad'
});

// NMX MySQL connection configuration
const redNMX = mysql.createConnection({
    host: '[ip]',
    user: '[username]',
    password: '[password]',
    database: '[database name]',
    port: '3306',
    connectTimeout: 20000, // Set the connection timeout to 20 seconds (adjust as needed)
});

// Connect to both MySQL servers
connection.connect((error) => {
    if (error) {
        console.error('Error connecting to Local MySQL server:', error);
        return;
    }
    console.log('Connected to Local MySQL server');
    
    // Now that the local connection is established, connect to RedNMX server
    redNMX.connect((redNMXError) => {
        if (redNMXError) {
            console.error('Error connecting to RedNMX MySQL server:', redNMXError);
            return;
        }
        console.log('Connected to RedNMX MySQL server');
        retrieveCallData();
    });
});

function retrieveCallData() {
    console.log("Retrieving call data, line 43.");

    // SQL query to get the latest 10 calls
    const sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM NFIRSMAIN ORDER BY DATETIMEALARM DESC LIMIT 10";

    redNMX.query(sqlQuery, (error, results, fields) => {
        if (error) {
            console.error('Error retrieving call data from MySQL:', error);
        } else {
            // Process the retrieved call data
            storeNewCalls(results);
        }
        // Close the RedNMX connection (if needed)
        // redNMX.end();
    });
}
```

I am getting an error output of:

Error connecting to Local MySQL server: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
at Connection._handleConnectTimeout (C:\Users\Ryan Pfister - FIRST\Documents\GitHub\CallTracker\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:409:13)
at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:628:28)
at Socket.emit (node:events:514:28)
at Socket.emit (node:domain:488:12)
at Socket._onTimeout (node:net:589:8)
at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:573:17)
at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7)
--------------------
.............
{
errorno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
syscall: 'connect',
fatal: true
}

What's weird is I can connect to the server via command line and using MySQL workbench, but not with node.js mySQL package. I have tried specifying the driver type. I looked at the mysql server log as well and did not see anything special.

I tried modifying my code several times, and ensuring there is no firewall blocking access, and that I had the right credentials, all to no luck.                                                                                                                                ............................................................